# How can I achieve faster access to this netcdf?

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray

I am selecting spatially and temporal data from this kind of NetCDF opened by

```
ds = xr.open_mfdataset(file_list):
```

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 576, lon: 1152, time: 1464)
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float32 0.0 0.3125 0.625 0.9375 ... 359.0625 359.375 359.6875
  * lat      (lat) float32 89.761 89.4514 89.1399 ... -89.1399 -89.4514 -89.761
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1980-04-01T01:00:00 ... 1980-06-01
Data variables:
    uasmean  (lat, lon, time) float32 dask.array<shape=(576, 1152, 1464), chunksize=(576, 1152, 720)>
    vasmean  (lat, lon, time) float32 dask.array<shape=(576, 1152, 1464), chunksize=(576, 1152, 720)>
Attributes:
    Creator:  NCAR - CISL RDA (dattore)
    history:  Mon Aug 11 12:24:36 2014: ncatted -a history,global,d,, -O Wind...
```

I achieved to get the correct subset in time and lon/lat using:

```
ds = ds.where((ds.time >= np.datetime64(date_ini)) & (ds.time <= np.datetime64(date_end)), drop=True)
ds = ds.where((ds.lon >= lonlat[0]) & (ds.lon <= lonlat[1]) & (ds.lat >= lonlat[2]) & (ds.lat <= lonlat[3]), drop=True)
```

And finally to extract this information in my target format I use a loop over the time to convert the information to a dataframe that I export to csv after:

```
# for t in ds['time']:
t = ds['time'][0]    

# Select time and convert to dataframe
df = ds.sel(time=t).to_dataframe()
```

My problem is that the conversion to dataframe is slow and I know that the originals netCDF are written in order to optimize the extraction of temporal series instead of extracting maps as I am trying to do. I know that is possible to change the sort of coordinates and write a new netCDF in order to speed this up, but the database is a too big... so it is not an option. Do you know if there is any other way to speed up this extraction??

Thank you all in advance!!!

P.D.: I attached the complete script of this block of code I am using to check the performance...

```
import os
import random
import shutil
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import scipy.io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

start_time = time.time()

files = glob('*.nc')
lonlat = [-5, 10, 50, 64]

date_ini = datetime(1980, 4, 28)
date_end = datetime(1980, 5, 3)

ds = xr.open_mfdataset(files)

print('[Processing 2D winds]')
# create date list to loop over folders
dates = pd.date_range(start=date_ini - timedelta(days=1), end=date_end + timedelta(days=1), freq='D')

# Create date list of files to open
file_list = []
for date in dates:
    file_list.append('Wind_CFS_Global_' + date.strftime('%Y.%m') + '.nc')

# Delete repeated elements
file_list = list(dict.fromkeys(file_list))
print(file_list)

# load data
ds = xr.open_mfdataset(file_list)
# Select temporal subset
ds = ds.get(['uasmean','vasmean'])
ds = ds.where((ds.time >= np.datetime64(date_ini)) & (ds.time <= np.datetime64(date_end)), drop=True)

# from 0º,360º to -180º,180º
ds['lon'] = (ds.lon + 180) % 360 - 180
ds = ds.sortby('lon', 'lat')

ds = ds.where((ds.lon >= lonlat[0]) & (ds.lon <= lonlat[1]) & (ds.lat >= lonlat[2]) & (ds.lat <= lonlat[3]), drop=True)

print(ds)

currents_list = []
# for t in ds['time']:
t = ds['time'][0]    

# Select time and depth array
df = ds.sel(time=t).to_dataframe()

# reset index because longitude latitude are as multi-index and I want them as columns
df = df.reset_index()

# sort data-rows for TESEO: longitude, latitude (ascending)
df = df.sort_values(['lon', 'lat'])

# generate full file path
outfile = 'winds_' + df['time'][0].strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M') + '.txt'

# export to ascii without separator, without header neither index column, replace nan by 0 and set 3 floating numbers
df.to_csv(path_or_buf=outfile,
          sep=' ',
          columns=['lon', 'lat', 'uasmean', 'vasmean'],
          header=False,
          index=False,
          na_rep=0,
          float_format='%.3f'
          )

elapsed_time = (time.time() - start_time)
print('Elapsed time: {} sec.'.format(elapsed_time))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a big improvement in the performance doing this:

- convert all the Xarray dataset to a dataframe
- loop over time directly in the dataframe

That makes a really big difference! I was looping over time and converting this shorter dataset to dataframe that is really inefficient!

Best regards!